# Using debug NPM module with fish shell

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, fish

I am currently using the npm module titled [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) during development of a Node.JS application. As I understand it, it outputs the debugging results through the use of the DEBUG environment variable (?) using the bash command:

`DEBUG=* node index.js`

This works as intended for bash, but I was wondering what the equivalent would be using the Fish shell, I've just started using it and I like it but it would be great if I could get this functionality as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For fish, to set an environment variable for a specific command, just use `env`

```
env DEBUG="*" node index.js
```

You'll have to quote or escape the wildcard.

This approach works for bash too.